# How to act in face of webpacker deprecations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

Using the latest version of rails 6.1.1  `rails webpacker:install` the following warnings are brought up.  Given that they are recipes that are brought in with the rails version, how should one comport themselves in view of this information?

```
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > node-gyp > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request > har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
```

Answer (score 0):

> Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.

In practice, I'm running this in a container with Node 16 and don't find that chokidar breaks. For the moment, in 2022, I'm just ignoring those messages until we migrate to Rails 7 JS packaging which will be different.

Your usage may be different from mine of course.